# Why is Hilbert's Seventeenth Problem important?

Tags: mathematics, logic, hilbert

I'm self-learning about Model Theory and I just got to the proof of Hilbert's 17th Problem via Model Theory of Real Closed Fields. The 17th problem asks to show that a non-negative rational function must be the sum of squares of rational functions.

It seems to me that I lack a strong enough understanding of the context of the problem to understand its significance. Why did Hilbert think it was important enough to include it as one of his 23 problems?

Comment: Hilbert had done work on this topic already and knew a positive-definite polynomial in 2 variables need not be a sum of squares of polynomials (working over real numbers) but is a sum of squares of rational functions. So the question in $n$ variables interested him. To him, the problems he posed were not supposed to be anything like the most important questions for the 20th century. They were just “particular problems [from] which an advancement of science may be expected.”

Comment: Continuing on with the "advancement of science" theme, there was a Quanta article from 2018 ("[A Classical Math Problem Gets Pulled Into the Modern World](https://www.quantamagazine.org/a-classical-math-problem-gets-pulled-into-the-modern-world-20180523/)") that describes how Hilbert's 17th problem plays a role in certain "real-world" optimization problems. No doubt far from Hilbert's motivation for inclusion on his list, but it shows that the problem had merit beyond simply satisfying an idle curiosity.